# Send SIGWINCH from the keyboard

Tags: terminal, keyboard, signals

[The Wikipedia page on Unix Signals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#Miscellaneous_signals) says:

> **SIGWINCH**
>
> The SIGWINCH signal is sent to a process when its controlling terminal changes its size (a **win**dow **ch**ange).

Is it possible to send SIGWINCH from the keyboard?

If so, how?

Comment: sure - but the syntax is system-dependent (`SIGWINCH` is not in [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/kill.html))  ``man kill``.

Comment: You may also consult the [implementation discussion](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=1151).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. use `pgrep myprogram` to get pid of myprogram
2. `kill -SIGWINCH pid`

you may use

```
kill -l
```

to get list of supported signal in numerical form.

```
kill -28 1234
```

Comment: So, the answer is "no"? (looking for a way to send the signal quickly to current terminal process, without opening a new terminal)

Answer (score -1):

The answer I was looking for was:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

Comment: I knew and tried this, but it didn't work to reformat a `man` page after the terminal size changed. I suspect that the *`roff` output is not regenerated in such cases.

Comment: You have a gross misunderstanding about (1) what handles Ctrl-L and how it's supposed to work, (2) what `SIGWINCH` is and what problem it's supposed to solve, and (3) how `man(1)` works.  Way, way too much for a single post.